# After close Scanner(System.in), create Scanner(System.in), but not operate correctly

Tags: java

e.g)

```
public void a(){
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     String a = input.nextLine();
     ....
     input.close();
}

public void b(){
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     int b = scan.nextInt();
     ....
     scan.close();
}
```

This Scanner does not operate correctly.
But after remove close(), it works correctly.

I guess the reason is the 'System.in' have a problem.

Please give me answer.

Thank you

+) First call input.nextLine() in a(), and then call scan.nextInt() in b().
   I have the error such as NoSuchElementException.

Comment: *Attempting to perform search operations after a scanner has been closed will result in an IllegalStateException.* Is that what you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void b(){
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     int b = scan.nextLine();
     ....
     input.close();
}
```

this should not be `input.close();`! `b()` method cannot access the `input` variable of `a()` method. So you should replace it with `scan.close()`

```
public void b(){
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     int b = scan.nextLine();
     ....
     scan.close();
}
```